# Question about the chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f(x_1,x_2) = (x_2 e^{x_1^2}, x_1x_2 - \cos x_1, \sin (x_1x_2)) $ and $f(y_1,y_2,y_3) = (y_2^3 y_3 \sin(y_1), y_1 + y_2^2 y_3^3 ) $. I want to find the derivative of $g(f(x))$ ad $f(g(x)) $. DO I just have to compute

$$ Dg(f(x))[ (0,1)] =  Dg[f(0,1)] Df[(0,1)]  $$

???

Comment: Since $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are both functions from and to multidimensional spaces, the derivative you find eventually will be a Jacobian (or, equivalently, you need to decide which partial derivative to compute). The notation in your displayed formula _may_ refer to Jacobians and matrix multiplication, in which case it looks more or less right, but I don't see where you get $(0,1)$ from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should have said in the beginning, that you want the derivative calculated in $(0,1)$. Remember that $\mathrm{d}\left(g \circ f\right)_p = \mathrm{d}g_{f(p)} \cdot \mathrm{d}f_p$. But $\mathrm{d}g_{f(0,1)}$ and $\mathrm{d}f_{(0,1)}$ are just Jacobian matrices that you shouldn't have problem calculating.

Recording, if $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, then $\mathrm{d}f_p :\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, and since this is a linear mapping, we have a $2 \times3$ matriz associated, defined by: $[\mathrm{d}f_p]_{ij} = \dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(p)$, the $i$-th row of the matrix is the gradient of the $i$-th component of the function. Ok?